# Show the first page for a moment after redirecting to second page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, redirect

I am using jQuery mobile and doing simple redirecting to another page.

after the page redirecting, the requested page is showing, then the first page it showing up for a moment and then redirected to the requested page. i don't understand why it's happened.

Can someone know the reason and how to solve it?
this is my code:

```
 <a href="#CreateG3" data-transition="slide" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-prefetch >3/3</a>
```

Comment: show us the full html

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, you don't want the page to be shown for a moment? Or you want to "shot the first page for a moment after..." ?